# Allow @PostConstruct annotation on Google Guice based app

Tags: java, guice, jsr250

I'm starting my way with [google guice](https://github.com/google/guice).
Since guice does not support [jsr-250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSR_250) annotations out of the box I'm trying to bridge this gap. Specifically I'm interested on using [@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) and [@PreDestroy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html) annotations.

- I tried following [guiceyfruit](https://code.google.com/p/guiceyfruit/wiki/Maven) as [described here](https://devsurf.wordpress.com/2010/09/15/guice-automatic-injectionbinding-guicyfruit-integration-postconstructpredestroy-guicejndi-and-the-childinjector/) with no success.
- I tried [mycila](http://code.mycila.com/guice/) support for JSR-250 with no success (see section 3,  JSR-250): `injector = Guice.createInjector(Stage.PRODUCTION, new CloseableModule(), new Jsr250Module(), new MyModule());`
  Or using `Jsr250.newJsr250Module()` with no success.

Has anyone managed to use JSR-250 annotations in a guice based application and can show me how it is done?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/google/guice/issues/62#issuecomment-115452493 maybe this will help

Comment: I did my own simple implementation for this https://github.com/xvik/guice-ext-annotations (using TypeListener instead of ProvisionListener). But you should understand that guice philosophy is different from spring and if you follow it you should avoid implicit behaviour (see https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ModulesShouldBeFastAndSideEffectFree).

Comment: I guess I can make it work using shutdown hooks as described here: http://hellotojavaworld.blogspot.co.il/2010/11/runtimeaddshutdownhook.html

Comment: I made good experiences with mycilla, worked out of the box. Could you post your code? Maybe you did st wrong ...